# Calculating Speed of bicycle down a hill or coasting to a stop

Tags: newtonian-mechanics, drag, aerodynamics

I'm working on trying to employ physics into a bicycle training app and I'm using the equations from http://gribble.org/cycling/power_v_speed.html to convert power (from the indoor trainer or power meter) into speed.

It's all good until I stop peddling and thus have $0\mathrm{Watt}$ power coming from the trainer and basically is considered as coasting.

The Question:

1. How to model the speed from before I stop pedaling, say $v_1 = 30\mathrm{km/h}$ to when I stop completely $v_2 = 0\mathrm{km/h}$

The forces acting on the cyclist = $F_{total} = F_{gravity} + F_{rolling} + F_{drag}$

Since there's $0$ gradient, there's no gravitational force acting on the cyclist, leaving Rolling Resistance and Drag which is equivalent to $\approx 95\mathrm{Watt}$.

So I know that I need to use the $95\mathrm{Watt}$ as the base and then calc until the Roll+Drag = $0$ which is when $v_2=0$.

[image]

2. Same as #1 but this time with a descent.

This is what I have currently (the formulas are from the above link)

[image]

Terminal velocity is 51.8kmh (this is when all forces are cancelled out)

Edit : Based on @Ben51's help
This is what I calculated. Not entirely sure it's correct, especially the value of $$A^2 (the left table uses $v_0, the right table uses the equation which has v cancelled out)

Now when I plug in different initial speed values, the resultant data looks incorrect whereby a higher initial speed would result in a faster deceleration to 0km/h
[image]

Edit2 w/ further guidance from @Ben51
With the image provided in @Ben51's answer, verified the equation for A is correct and B should be using Fdrag and Froll with Newton as units (using Watts would have baked in the velocity). This then provided a good model. (but limited to -0.3% descent)

[image]

Excel File - https://www.dropbox.com/s/xhucdewvp3buj7w/Deceleration.xlsx?dl=0

Comment: By *deceleration*  you seem to mean "slowing down".   Does that imply *acceleration* means "speeding up"?  What is the meaning of negative deceleration? What about an object moving in the $-x$ direction having a positive acceleration?  Is it accelerating or decelerating?   Solution:  never use the word *decelerate*.

Comment: I'm facing exactly the same predicament on a little hobby cycling game I'm trying to code. May I ask on the solution you settled on and how the modelling of speed reduction under no power turned out?

Answer (score 0):

I just posted an answer suggesting numerical calculation.  I deleted it because, given the form of the drag forces laid out in the link you provided, there is a closed-form solution.  $F_{gravity}$ and $F_{rolling}$ are just constants, and $F_{drag}$ is proportional to velocity squared. Rather than copy all the constants from the link, I will define more streamlined ones, using the convention that forces acting to slow the bike down are positive: $$A^2=\frac{F_{drag}}{mv^2}, B^2=\frac{F_{gravity}+F_{rolling}}{m}.$$ With these definitions, and assuming that slope is either uphill or shallowly enough downhill that the rolling resistance is larger in magnitude than the gravitational force (in this latter case $F_{gravity}$ is negative), the velocity is governed by the separable ODE $$\frac{dv}{dt}=-A^2v^2-B^2.$$ This can be integrated directly to give $$v(t)=-\frac{B}{A} \tan (ABt-C),$$ where $C$ is a constant, which, to satisfy the initial conditions, must be set to $$C=\arctan(\frac{Av_0}{B}).$$ Note that this solution is only valid up until the moment that the bike stops.

**EDIT:**
Here is an image to show an example of what your result should look like. The meanings of the coefficients are explained in the link in your question.

[image]

Comment: thanks for responding. May I know what's ODE and what's C (constant) represents? In the definition of A, the velocity there is V1 or V2? (I'm assuming there's a diff as you wrote V and then V0 specifically). V0 = Start Velocity, V1 = End velocity (0 in my case). Unfortunately for me, all my college level physics, I've basically didn't use for quite a few decades. So I'm definitely struggling.

Comment: ODE is ordinary differential equation. C is just a constant of integration.  If you implement this, make sure you use tan and arctan functions that use radians as units rather than degrees.

Comment: In the definition of A, v is instantaneous velocity. It cancels out if you plug in the expression for the drag force. You will end up with A being equal to the drag coefficient times the area etc, but not depending on the velocity.

Comment: I plugged in the equations you provided (thanks again) into an excel to see what the result would look like. Could you please take a gander and determine if they(and which equation) are correct? additionally, when I plug in -ve slope values, it doesn't work. (eg: coasting down a hill for example)

Comment: just edited when I re-read your comment and saw that the units should be in radians (also excel uses radians for it's tan/atan). Now -ve slope doesn't give me errors. Could you verify it's correct? Finally, if there is additional force applied by the cyclist during the descent, where do I plug in the values to account for the additional speed increase?

Comment: For pedaling: As long as the forward force (as opposed to, say, the power) is held constant, you can just add the force into the definition of $B^2$. That has all the constant forces in it. The sign of this force is opposite of the rolling resistance. The net constant force needs to be backward, or this solution is not valid. It is only for cases where you eventually stop.

Comment: Been banging my head over this the entire day w/ lots of googling and reading thru literature but not getting anywhere. My Calculation for A seems to be suspect. Initially I used the equation for A where v is cancelled out and I was a happy camper, however when I inputted different starting velocity, the resultant output seems to be incorrect. (refer to my edited post again) and this threw me into a tailspin. Could you please verify where I went wrong?

Comment: I have not looked at your excel, but I added an image of what your output should look like.  Some things: you need to use m/s for speed; A and B do not depend on $v_0$; for $C_{rr}=0.004$ you can't have more downward slope than about $G=-0.5$% because you will never stop (as you requested in your question, this solution is for cases where you stop).

Comment: The Image w/ the values for A/B/C helped Immensely for troubleshooting. It verified my "A" was correct and I was using an incorrect Unit for B(I was using Watts - with velocity baked in) instead of N. Much Thanks for that. As for Crr, based on https://www.bicyclerollingresistance.com/road-bike-reviews, Crr can be as low as 0.0042@100psi (for 2 wheels). I find it surprising that that w/ G> -0.5% I would never stop. I'm pretty sure this isn't true in the real world as when I cycle and roll down a hill > -0.5% slope, I definitely will roll to a point where I need to put my foot down.

Comment: For this physics model, I'd like to mimic the real world cycling. eg: stop pedaling (0% gradient - 0w Power), speed decreases due to drag+rolling resistance until x kmh before I start pedaling, power > 0 and speed resumes. When descending a -5% gradient rolling from 30kmh to teminal velocity of 52kmh or if I pedal and add additional power to increase my speed above 52kmh. I apologise for not stating my exact desire in the original question. But 0% Gradient fits exactly into the "Erg mode" training. Maybe I should ask a diff question for modelling riding a virtual real world terrain?

Comment: For forcing that changes in time just do it numerically. Newton’s second law is $m\frac{\Delta v}{\Delta t}=\Sigma F$.  Choose a small $\Delta t$ like 0.01 sec, and iterate, using the velocity at each time step to compute the force, and then use that force to get the velocity for the next time step.

Comment: That's what I'm doing for when Power != 0 (https://bit.ly/2Nvsnc0), I iterate through different speeds to get the power that matches the power the cyclist is producing. However, I'm lost when Power = 0.